According to the Catholic Church, are demonic unclean spirits the ghosts of dead humans, or the presence of fallen angels?
1 Samuel 28:7-8 ESV The Medium of Endor Raises the Spirit of Samuel

Then Saul said to his servants, “Seek out for me a woman who is a
medium, that I may go to her and inquire of her.” And his servants
said to him, “Behold, there is a medium at Endor.”
So Saul disguised himself and put on other garments and went, he and
two men with him. And they came to the woman by night. And he said,
“Divine for me by a spirit and bring up for me whomever I shall name
to you.”

Luke 24:36-39 ESV Disciples Mistake Jesus for a Spirit

As they were talking about these things, Jesus himself stood among
them, and said to them, “Peace to you!” But they were startled and
frightened and thought they saw a spirit. And he said to them, “Why
are you troubled, and why do doubts arise in your hearts? See my hands
and my feet, that it is I myself. Touch me, and see. For a spirit does
not have flesh and bones as you see that I have.”

Matthew 12:43-45 ESV Return of an Unclean Spirit

“When an unclean spirit has gone out of a person, it passes through
waterless places seeking rest, but finds none. Then it says, ‘I will
return to my house from which I came.’ And when it comes, it finds the
house empty, swept, and put in order. Then it goes and brings with it
seven other spirits more evil than itself, and they enter and dwell
there, and the last state of that person is worse than the first. So
also will it be with this evil generation.”

The unclean spirits, demons, seek to possess a body and therefore torment people for control of their bodies to hurt themselves and others. Jesus cleansed people's souls by casting out the unclean spirits called "demons".

Are angels spirits which possess immortal bodies?

Are humans spirits which possess mortal bodies?

Are demons the unclean spirits of dead humans (and Nephilim) that find no rest after death?

Do the spirits of the righteous dead remain at rest until they are resurrected?

Are unclean spirits or demons the ghosts of dead people instead of fallen angels, which have spiritual bodies? Is this why the demons, which have no bodies, seek to possess one?



Normally this would be too many subquestions, but seeing as they're all yes/no questions I guess it will be alright.

The Roman Catholic charismatic renewal exorcist Father Richard McAlear, in one of his teaching tapes (that I listened to over 45 years ago), taught that there were demonic unclean spirits, poltergeist phenomena of earth bound souls of the saints on their way to heaven (which to him was purgatory) and the souls of the damned (from hell). In the teaching that I recall, Fr. McAlear didn't get into how the souls of the damned could manifest themselves.
Close to the Catholic view is the Lutheran view, articulated by John W. Montgomery in his "Principalities and Powers" book. He argues for a multi-level explanatory scheme for ghost claims:

Ghosts as telepathic hallucinations arising from the minds of the living.

Ghosts as telepathic hallucinations arising from the minds (brains) of the dead.

Ghosts as residual human aura.

Ghosts as the dead themselves, on their way to the reward determined once for all by their relationship or lack of relationship to Christ on earth, but not yet entered fully into that reward.

Ghosts as the damned sent back to haunt the living or as Satanic counterfeits of the dead.

Ghosts as the saved sent back to earth by God for a special mission.


Montgomery argues that the six explanatory levels offer the tools for dealing with most attested spectral phenomena. He suggests that sometimes one interpretation will best fit the data, sometimes another. He points out that no apparition offers apodictic proof of survival after death. That's because one can theoretically appeal to telepathy or the human aura as an explanation.

This was a sufficient answer, thank you!

According to Catholic tradition, angels and demons are the same kind of being. They are incorporeal, intelligent substances with free will and personality. They were created on the first day of creation. Many Catholic theologians hold that the "light" created on the first day was the light of reason, which the angels possess. The demons are fallen angels. In the beginning, at the time when angels were created, they were immediately infused with all of the knowledge they needed to make a rational choice for or against God. Those who chose Him received their eternal reward consisting in the beatific vision. They see God's essence directly. Those who rejected Him were cast out and became demons. Both angels and demons have the ability to influence the material world.
To answer your five questions directly.

No. Angels are immortal spirits, but they do not possess bodies at all. They are pure spirit.

Humans are Hylomorphic. We possess bodies and souls, and properly are composed of both. Our bodies are mortal on account of sin, but our souls are immortal because we possess that same reason which angels and demons possess. Those of us who go to heaven are like angels after death, and those who go to hell are like demons. On the last day, our bodies will be restored, and they will either be glorified or grotesque depending on whether we have eternal life or eternal damnation. This restoration will happen because man is, properly speaking, embodied. He is body and soul together.

Demons are just fallen angels. The souls of damned humans are like demons, in that they are suffering spirits, but unlike demons, they have no power to influence the material world. Any unclean spirits which interact with the world are fallen angels (ie demons), and not human beings.

Yes, they have the beatific vision alongside the angels and remain at rest in God. Unlike the angels, they have no power to influence the material world, but they do have friendship with God and can pray for us.

Demons seek to possess human bodies because it gives them a more direct opportunity to tempt people to mortal sin, and to cause disorder in God's ordered universe. The things they do are done out of hatred of God and hatred of mankind. If they can tempt people to mortal sin, they can take a sick kind of intellectual pleasure in the damnation of those people (assuming those people don't repent), and they can also presume themselves as having taken vengeance upon God because they harmed His creation. I would not speculate about the particular motives of demons beyond this. They are people (though not human people), and are as complex as any other persons.



I am unsatisfied with this answer. I need more wisdom to understand this.

@JoshuaB what is unclear?

You said that angels do not have immortal bodies, which to me makes no sense.

@JoshuaB angels are purely spiritual beings, so they don't have bodies at all. What about angels not having immortal bodies is causing confusion?
